# <small> tag makes height of paragraph larger

Tags: html, css, baseline

I have the following fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/tompazourek/sn5jp/

```
<p>some normal-sized text</p>

<p>some <small>small</small>-sized text</p>
```

---

```
p { line-height: 20px }
```

---

When I inspect the page in Chrome, I find out that the computed height of the first paragraph is 20px, but the computed height of the second paragraph is 21px.

Why is the `<small>` tag causing these problems? **How can I fix this?**

Every occurence of `<small>` in the paragraph text messes up my [baseline grid](http://alistapart.com/article/settingtypeontheweb).

---

**EDIT:** I later also found an interesting article relevant to this topic: [Deep dive CSS: font metrics, line-height and vertical-align](http://iamvdo.me/en/blog/css-font-metrics-line-height-and-vertical-align).

Comment: This is really mysterious. If you replace the `small` element by a `span` element and test with different font sizes, you’ll notice that anything smaller (even by one pixel) than the parent element’s font size makes the parent element 21px tall, whereas a larger font size up to 19px does not do that (the height stays at 20px).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Explanation:

There are a few things happening here.

In your example, the `small` element is an [inline-level element](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-level), which means that its vertical alignment is determined by the [`vertical-align` property](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align).

The default `vertical-align` value is `baseline`, which means that the baseline of the `small` element will be aligned to the baseline of the parent box:

> Align the baseline of the box with the baseline of the parent box. If the box does not have a baseline, align the bottom margin edge with the parent's baseline.

Next, you need to consider the [`line-height` property](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-line-height) and how it is [calculated](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#line-height). You also need to take [leading and half-leading](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#leading) into account. In CSS, half-leading is determined by finding the difference between the element's `line-height` and `font-size`, dividing that in half, and then placing the calculated amount of space above and below the text.

For illustration, here is an example image demonstrating this ([taken from W3.org](https://www.w3.org/Talks/2008/0911-CSS-Amsterdam/line-height.png)):

> [image]

Since the `line-height` is `20px`, and the `small` element has a `font-size` of `13px`, then we can determine that `3.5px` of space is added above and below the `small` element's text:

```
(20px - 13px) / 2 =  3.5px
```

Likewise, if we calculate the half-leading of the surronding text nodes, which have a `font-size` of `16px`, then we can determine that `2px` of space is added above and below the surrounding text.

```
(20px - 16px) / 2 =  2px
```

Now if we relate these half-leading space calculations back to the `vertical-align` property, you will notice that more space is actually being added below the baseline of the `small` element. This explains why the computed height of the `p` element containing the `small` element was larger than the computed height of the other `p` element.

With that being said, you would expect the computed height of the `p` element to continue increasing as the `font-size` of the `small` element decreases. To further illustrate this point, you will notice that the computed height of the `p` element is `23px` when the `font-size` of the `small` element is set to `6px`.

```css
p { line-height: 20px; }
small { font-size: 6px; }
```

```html
<p>some normal-sized text</p>
<p>some <small>small</small>-sized text</p>
```

---

#### Potential Workarounds:

Since we know that the height difference results from the extra space that is added to the `baseline`, we could change the `vertical-align` value of the `small` element to `top`:

```css
p { line-height: 20px; }
small { vertical-align: top; }
```

```html
<p>some normal-sized text</p>
<p>some <small>small</small>-sized text</p>
```

Alternatively, you could give the `small` element a `line-height` of `17px`, which would result in `2px` of space being added above and below the element (which is the same amount of space that is added for the surrounding text like we calculated above).

```
// Surrounding text that is 16px:
(20px - 16px) / 2 =  2px

// Small element text that is 13px:
(17px - 13px) / 2 =  2px
```

```css
p { line-height: 20px; }
small { line-height: 17px; }
```

```html
<p>some normal-sized text</p>
<p>some <small>small</small>-sized text</p>
```

However, you really don't want to be calculating any of that and hardcoding it, which means that you should just use a relative `line-height` and omit the `px` units.

Since the the `font-size` is `16px` and the desired `line-height` value is `20px`, you would divide the `line-height` by the `font-size` and get `1.25`:

```css
p { line-height: 1.25; }
```

```html
<p>some normal-sized text</p>
<p>some <small>small</small>-sized text</p>
```

If you don't want to use a relative `line-height: 1.25`, and you want to continue using `line-height: 20px`, then you could of course reset the `small` element's `line-height` value back to the initial value, which is `normal`.

```css
p { line-height: 20px; }
small { line-height: normal; }
```

```html
<p>some normal-sized text</p>
<p>some <small>small</small>-sized text</p>
```

Comment: Okay, you just found a way how to fix the problem. Kudos for that :). But still the `<small>` text aligned to the top looks weird. Also I still don't truly understand the reason and the mechanism of what is happening underneath.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed this issue again somewhere and thought it deserved a proper explanation. Thank you again for this elaborate answer :) it looks great. I'll keep the question open for some time, but it looks like you'll win the bounty. :)

Comment: Now this is a combination of good question & good answer I haven't seen in a long time. I have pondered this question for so long but couldn't explain it. Thanks both of you :)

Comment: @JoshCrozier I read your answer again in detail today, and I still don't understand everything. I follow you until the `vertical-align` workaround, but then the last three `line-height` workarounds still involve something I don't quite get. I made [another snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/zv7kfqsb/3/) where the text is wrapped onto two lines, and the second paragraph consists only of `<small>` text with `line-height: 17px`. What I don't get is why both paragraphs are still equal height of 40px. Somehow I'd assume that if the `<small>` sets line height to 17px, it will be only 34px high.

Answer (score 1):

The alternative to the answers posted by Josh Crozier would be to reset small line-height alltogether:

```css
p { line-height: 20px }
small {line-height: initial;}
```

```html
<p>some normal-sized text</p>

<p>some <small>small</small>-sized text</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a relative value for `line-height`. In your case, the base font size is 16px, so a 20px line height in relative units would be `1.25`

```css
p { line-height: 1.25; }
```

```html
<p>some normal-sized text</p>
<p>some <small>small</small>-sized text</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This happen because of small tag has font-size:smaller and p tag has bigger size then small tag so this difference of small and p tag making this problem. When you are putting small tag into p tag then increase height because small tag taking small space then p tag.

Soving this problem you have to give line height to small tag 19px, like this:

```css
p { line-height: 20px }
small{line-height: 19px}
```

```html
<p>some normal-sized text</p>

<p>some <small>small</small>-sized text</p>
```