# Why does using em font-sizes ruin line-height?

Tags: css, fonts, font-size

I set a font-size on my body element as 19px - then from there, I am using em for different kinds of things, but there is an issue and line-heights are irregular... example, I use font-size: 0.6 em and the line height is uneven, it's driving me crazy!!

BTW using bootstrap - they set a line height of 1.428571429.

Tried using line-height normal and tested with different em sizes... There should be something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you describe your code instead of showing us your code?

Answer (score -1):

Use `rem` instead: https://css-tricks.com/confused-rem-em/

`em` is "ratio compare to parent font size"

Comment: behaves the same if I use rem

Comment: Oooh, uneven `line-height`... does this one sound familiar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23461423/small-tag-makes-height-of-paragraph-larger ?

Comment: :( tried changing to rem and even px and its the same..uneven at certain sizes, and its not even a span or small, its a p inside a div....

Comment: I suppose in this case we will need a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to see what's going on.